Issue While Navigation in the Angular application
  this.router.navigate(['/d/admin', this.uuid], {
            state: { username: this.user.username },
          });

I'm using like this to navigate in angular project but the issue that i'm facing is that sometimes i got the proper response from the backend but it won't navigate to the page and not getting any issue in the console. What could be the prossible error

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible stackblitz where the issue happens

After Successfully Server response tyring to navigate using the above navigate feature...but not able to navigate
